# Linker command failed with exit code 1 when i archive

Tags: ios

when I run on my iphone6 in DEBUG and RELEASE,it is ok.
but when I archive, I have a problem.

[image]

Comment: Please don't link the error message, include it in the question, it's only text after all.

Comment: So. Do you use a `cocoapods`? Ensure that you open a `.xcworkspace` file, not a `.xcodeproj`.

Comment: Have you examined the build log to see what directories are being used by the linker?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?